# Set a ASP.NET WEB.API model property to be read-only for consumers of the API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

What's the best way of ensuring that a property of a model can only be set by the ASP.NET WEB.API service? To a consumer of the service, that property is read-only.

For example:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Required]
    public string CanBeSetByConsumer { get; set; }

    // Can only be set by the service
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class MyModelController : ApiController
{
    public MyModel Get(int id)
    {
        // get MyModel by Id
        return new MyModel();
    }

    public MyModel Post(MyModel myData)
    {
        // save myData to a store and generate an ID
        // return myData with ID populated with a 201 Created
    }
}
```

In the above example, the consumer of the API can `POST`:

```
{
  "CanBeSetByConsumer" : "SomeValue"
}
```

The consumer can also `GET`:

```
{
  "Id" : 1234,
  "CanBeSetByConsumer" : "SomeValue"
}
```

What I would like to do is return a `400 BAD REQUEST` if the client `POST`s:

```
{
  "Id" : 1234,
  "CanBeSetByConsumer" : "SomeValue"
}
```

Comment: One way would be to exclude the `Id` property from the Post model.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it. Note that the POST model does not contain the `Id` property.

```
public class MyGetModel
{
    [Required]
    public string CanBeSetByConsumer { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class MyPostModel
{
    [Required]
    public string CanBeSetByConsumer { get; set; }
}

public class MyModelController : ApiController
{
    public MyGetModel Get(int id)
    {
        // get MyModel by Id
        return new MyGetModel();
    }

    public MyGetModel Post(MyPostModel myData)
    {
        // save myData to a store and generate an ID
        // return myGetData with ID populated with a 201 Created
    }
}
```

Then if you have a lot of shared properties, you can have both of these inherit from an `abstract class MyModel`.

Another way to do it could be to add an action filter to the post action. In that action filter class, you would override the `OnActionExecuting` method, inspect the POST values collection for a value under the `Id` key, and set your 400 BAD REQUEST response there.

```
public class PreventIdValueAttribute
    : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // check request for id value, and if present,
        // set the result to a 400 bad request HttpResponseMessage
    }
}

[PreventIdValue]
public MyModel Post(MyModel myData)
{
    // save myData to a store and generate an ID
    // return myData with ID populated with a 201 Created
}
```

Note that with the second option, your `MyModel` instance will still have an `Id` value in the `Post` action, but its value will be zero.